# jquery post function work with text input but not hidden input

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I make a form with 2 input, one is text another is hidden that store the value of my variables. Then I write a jquery script with post method to pass the value to another php file which will insert the values to a database, But only the value from text input are inserted, the value from hidden input doesn't work. 
Here are the form and the jquery script:

```
<?php
include_once('header.php');
$uid = $_GET['uid'];
echo $uid;
[enter image description here][1]?>
 <form>
        <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
        <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?php echo $uid; ?>">
        <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
    </form>
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submitmsg").click(function () {
            var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
            var clientid = $("#uid").val();
            $.post("includes/postchat.php", {text: clientmsg,uid: clientid});
            $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
            return false;
        });
```

And here is the postchat.php file:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['u_uid'])) {
include('dbh-inc.php');
$text = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['text']);
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$date_current = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$user = $_SESSION['u_uid'];
if ($user = 'one') {

    if ($text != '') {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO messages (body, user_from, date_sent, user_to) VALUES (

            '$text',
            '$user',
            '$date_current',
            '$uid'    
        )";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
```

My table in database after submit:

Comment: There is no element with the ID of "uid", as referenced by `var clientid = $("#uid").val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
<input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?php echo $uid; ?>">
```

into this

```
<input type="hidden" id="uid" name="uid" value="<?php echo $uid; ?>">
```

As you have taken only name as uid but try to get the value of #uid which is not present

Answer (score 0):

Put the id field in the hidden element as uid.

```
<input type="hidden" id="uid" name="uid" value="<?php echo $uid; ?>">
```

In JQuery if you are accessing elements using '#' it means that you are accessing them by their ids.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As the answers stated before, there is no element with id uid.
You should either change your element tag to

```
<input type="hidden" id="uid" name="uid" value="<?php echo $uid; ?>">
```

Or use the following jQuery code:

```
var clientid = $("input[name='uid']").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
 <form>
        <input name="usermsg" type="text" size="63" />
        <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?php echo $uid; ?>">
        <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  value="Send" />
 </form>
<script>
$(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("includes/postchat.php", $(this).serialize());
        $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

note

`$(this).serialize()` will serialize all form fields, so you can easily add more fields without adding them one by one and you don't need to set any id.